# Can't get C2HS with "foreign" Pointers to work

Tags: haskell, ffi, c2hs

## General Information

I'm currently experimenting with the C->Haskell (C2HS) Interface Generator for Haskell. At the first glace, it was just awesome, I interfaced a rather complicated C++ library (using a small `extern C`-wrapper) in just a couple of hours. (And I never did any FFI before.)

There was just one problem: How to get the memory allocated in the C/C++ library freed? I found `{#pointer ... foreign #}` in the [C2HS documentation](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/haskell/c2hs/docu/implementing.html#id315561) and that looks exactly like what I'm after. Since my C-wrapper turns the C++ library into a library with referential transparency with a functional interface, the Haskell Storage Manager should be able to do the hard work for me :-). Unfortunately, I was not able to get this working. To better explain my problem, I set up a small [demo project on GitHub](https://github.com/weissi/c2hs-experiments) that has the same properties as the C/C++ library+wrapper but hasn't the overhead. As you can see, the library is completely safe to use with `pure unsafe` FFI.

## Demo Project

On GitHub, I created a [small demo project](https://github.com/weissi/c2hs-experiments) organized as follows:

### C library

The C library is very simple and useless: You can pass it an integer and you can get as many integers (currently `[0..n]`) back from the library. Remember: The library is useless, just a demo. The interface is quite simple, too: The function `LTIData lti_new_data(int n)` will (after passing a integer) return you some kind of opaque object containing allocated data of the C library. The library has also two accessor functions `int lti_element_count(LTIData data)` and `int lti_get_element(LTIData data, int n)`, the former will return the number of elements and the latter will return you element `n`. Ah, and last but not least, the user of the library should after using it free the opaque `LTIData` using `void lti_free_data(LTIData data)`.

- [Experiment/C2HSBinding/Foreign/lib_to_interface.h](https://github.com/weissi/c2hs-experiments/blob/master/Experiment/C2HSBinding/Foreign/lib_to_interface.h)
- [Experiment/C2HSBinding/Foreign/lib_to_interface.c](https://github.com/weissi/c2hs-experiments/blob/master/Experiment/C2HSBinding/Foreign/lib_to_interface.c)

### Low-level Haskell Binding

The low-level Haskell Binding is set up using C2HS, you can find it in

- [Experiment/C2HSBinding/Foreign/HsLTI.chs](https://github.com/weissi/c2hs-experiments/blob/master/Experiment/C2HSBinding/Foreign/HsLTI.chs)

### High-level Haskell API

For fun I also set up kind of a [high-level Haskell API](https://github.com/weissi/c2hs-experiments/blob/master/Experiment/C2HSBinding/HsLTIHighlevel.hs) using the low-level API binding and a [simple driver program](https://github.com/weissi/c2hs-experiments/blob/master/Experiment/C2HSBinding/TestHsLTIHighlevel.hs) that uses the high-level API. Using the driver program and e.g. valgrind one is easily able to see the leaked memory (for every parameter `p_1, p_2, ..., p_n` the library does `\sum_{i = 1..n} 1 + p_i` allocations; easily observable as below):

```
$ valgrind dist/build/TestHsLTI/TestHsLTI 100             2>&1 | grep -e allocs -e frees
==22647==   total heap usage: 184 allocs, 74 frees, 148,119 bytes allocated

$ valgrind dist/build/TestHsLTI/TestHsLTI 100 100         2>&1 | grep -e allocs -e frees
==22651==   total heap usage: 292 allocs, 80 frees, 181,799 bytes allocated

$ valgrind dist/build/TestHsLTI/TestHsLTI 100 100 100     2>&1 | grep -e allocs -e frees
==22655==   total heap usage: 400 allocs, 86 frees, 215,479 bytes allocated

$ valgrind dist/build/TestHsLTI/TestHsLTI 100 100 100 100 2>&1 | grep -e allocs -e frees
==22659==   total heap usage: 508 allocs, 92 frees, 249,159 bytes allocated
```

### Current State of the Demo

You should be able to clone, compile and run the [project](https://github.com/weissi/c2hs-experiments.git) by simply typing `git clone https://github.com/weissi/c2hs-experiments.git && cd c2hs-experiments && cabal configure && cabal build && dist/build/TestHsLTI/TestHsLTI`

## So what's the Problem again?

The problem is that the project only uses `Foreign.Ptr` and not the "managed" version `Foreign.ForeignPtr` using C2HS's `{#pointer ... foreign #}` and I can't get it to work. In the demo project I also added a [`.chs` file trying to use these foreign pointers](https://github.com/weissi/c2hs-experiments/blob/2192a229c48ae367ba5b9c1c97f4c0c4cc288ec4/Experiment/C2HSBinding/Foreign/HsLTIManaged.chs) but it does not work :-(. I tried it very hard but I didn't have any success.

And there is one thing I don't understand, too: How to tell GHC using C2HS how to free the library's data. The demo project's library provides a function `void lti_free_data(LTIData data)` that should get called to free the memory. But GHC can't guess that!?! If GHC uses regular a `free()`, not all of the memory will get freed :-(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved: I found [this file doing something similar](http://darcsden.com/komadori/HsQML/browse/src/Graphics/QML/Internal/Objects.chs) on the internet and was able to solve it :-).

Everything it needed was some boilerplate marshalling code:

```
foreign import ccall "lib_to_interface.h &lti_free_data"
  ltiFreeDataPtr :: FunPtr (Ptr (LTIDataHs) -> IO ())


newObjectHandle :: Ptr LTIDataHs -> IO LTIDataHs
newObjectHandle p = do
  fp <- newForeignPtr ltiFreeDataPtr p
  return $ LTIDataHs fp
```

Here's the [final managed (`ForeignPtr`) verion of the `.chs` file](https://github.com/weissi/c2hs-experiments/blob/master/Experiment/C2HSBinding/Foreign/HsLTIManaged.chs).

Comment: It looks like the latest version of c2hs has improvements in this area: http://www.skybluetrades.net/blog/posts/2015/03/30/c2hs-snowmelt.html#finalizers-for-foreign-pointers